# IOS: Multipeer Connectivity Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, multipeer-connectivity

I created an app with this code multipeer connectivity master / slave
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20703659/2787079

So when I switch the ViewController I cant "`SendDataToPeers`".
The error says "no peers connected."

Any hint or tips how i can call the gunction "`SendDataToPeers`" in a another ViewController with the same instance / session from the first one in Objective C
I don't want to connect again the slaves, they must stay connected.

Comment: Why don't you use a singleton class that manages your connections? This can be shared between the classes without dropping the connection.

Answer (score 2):

Create a single class to manage all Multipeer Connections (like MCController.swift) and instantiate it as a singleton within your app delegate.This way, this single object (and the  current connection state) can be accessed by all view controllers, much in the same way that UserDefauts is.